How can I learn to identify the class (P, NP, etc.) of a discrete optimization problem?
Suppose we have a discrete optimization problem, and we need to find an algorithm to solve it. Before we start, we would like to understand what class this problem belongs to. Because if it is an NP class problem, we can spend a lot of time to find a polynomial algorithm).
How can I learn to determine what class (P or NP) problem belongs to? Please recommend books, courses or other materials on this topic.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This is probably a better question for Stackoverflow.

@JohnDouma cs.stackexchange.com rather than Stackoverflow IMO…

This is quite a wide question.
First, search for polynomial by checking important polynomial classes: Horn clauses, linear algebra problem, linear programming problems (including some hiding with total unimodularity, such as flow, circulation, assignment problems...)
If it fails, search for obvious reduction to a classical NP-complete problem (X3C, hamiltonian path, subset sum, 3-colorability, ...)
After that, the problem may be non-trivial, so you have to do a lot of research on similar problems to find a reference or come up with your own algorithm or reduction.
Naturally, the more examples of polynomial algorithms and NP-complete problems you know, the easier it will be to classify your problem.
A great resource for examples of NP-complete problems is the Garey and Johnson.
If your problem concerns graphs, graph classes is a great resource (both for finding a polynomial algorithm or establishing hardness). The equivalent of this site exists for scheduling problems.

Too "wide" of an guess at an answer. Unfocused question $\to$ unfocused answer.
